# Use a string (representing a logical operator) in a Python expression

Tags: python, operators, expression

Is it possible to somehow cast a string of, say, `or` or `and` into a form that is recognizable as a logical operator?

For example, is it possible to do something like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
o = {item1:'or'}

for i in l:
    if i > 4 o[item1] i < 0:
        print i
```

where `o[item1]` is recognized as a valid `or` logical operator?

Comment: It is possible to create an equivalent equivalent (fsvo) expression, but it is not possible to use it like that - which is merely invalid syntax - and the expression itself needs to be altered.

Comment: XY problem: why do you think you need this?

Comment: With some trickery you could get an `(i > 4) |o[item1]| (i < 0)` syntax to work (without short-circuiting) but you'd never use that in any real code so it's not much more than a parlour trick.  Is there a particular problem you think this would help with?  Maybe there's a better way to solve it.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the question I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691990/python-pyqt-qtablewidet-how-to-implement-an-advanced-search-function

Comment: @DSM: and you could actually use a lot of different delimiters, like `a <o[x]> b` or `a **o[x]** b` or even `a %o[x]% b`...the possibilities are endless! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `operator` package:

```
import operator

o = {item1: operator.or_}

if o[item1](i>4, i<0):
    ...
```

Note that `or_` does not short-circuit, like `or` does. If you really need the short-circuit behaviour, you can use `eval` (but this is in general not recommended).